# JavaScript Login Form Not Validating

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, authentication

Good Evening,

I am trying to create a simple JavaScript login form that will validate by checking only 1 specific email address which has been declared and 1 password that has been declared.

However, no matter what is typed into the fields, even if nothing is present, once the submit button is clicked, the user is directed to the desired page.

I need it to only allow the desired page if the email address and password are the correct.  Otherwise, notify them that it is incorrect.

Here is a link to `[codepen][1]` so you can see the page and script.

```
https://codepen.io/m0rrisim0/pen/bmzyqj
```

Any help is appreciated in figuring out why the script is not validating.

Comment: When the user presses submit a POST request is sent to the server and the browser will proceed to that page. `onsubmit` is simply an event that fires when the user presses submit, it doesn't stop the actual POST request from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the attribute value from document.getElementById method,
 like the following example: document.getElementById("UserName").value

```
function validate() {
    'use strict';

    var UserName = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
    var email = "adrian@tissue.com";
    var Password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
    var pass = "welcome1";

    if ((UserName == email) && (Password == pass)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("UserName and/or Password Do Not Match");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your form's inputs lack the id atrribute and should return the function on submit event.

```
<form action="Issues.html" method="post" id="loginform" onsubmit="return validate()">
    UserName:
    <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName">
    <br>
    <br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was `getElementById()`, this function requires a argument and cause a error. Because of this error the line `loginform.onsubmit = validate;` was never reached so the submit button submit the form without calling a validate function.
There is no need to put this line inside the if statement, but if you want you can change a little bit to `getElementById` without the parentesis, this way it evaluates to a function that in js is truthy.
You can check a working version of you code here:

```
if (document && document.getElementById) {
    var loginform = document.getElementById('loginform');  
    loginform.onsubmit = validate;
}
```

https://codepen.io/francispires/pen/mzvYKX
You can improve this validation